# return names of list where elements of vector and list are equal

Tags: r

I have list of lists, each of inside lists contain one or more vectors:

```
codes <- list(
'traincodes' = list(c('2.29*', '99.49'), c('78.78')),   
'traincodes2' = list(c('02.24*')))
```

I want to check each element of vector d:

```
d = c('02.24*', '78.78')
```

Does each first element of lists 'traincodes' and 'traincodes2' contain element of vector d. And if it's TRUE return vector with names of lists, where it exists.

My attempts were not successful:

```
for (i in seq_along(codes))
 {for (k in seq_along(codes[[i]]))
  {l = sapply(codes[[i]][[1]][[k]], function(x) d == x )}}
```

which returns not what I want

```
     02.24*
1    TRUE
2    FALSE
```

But where is an info about second element of d - '78.78'?
In general my purpose is return names of list where elements of vector and list are equal, something like this:

```
     d
1    traincodes2
2    Na
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try: ( I changed the name of codes to make it easier to differentiate.

```
codes <- list(
'traincodes1' = list(c('2.29*', '99.49'), c('78.78')),
'traincodes2' = list(c('02.24*')))
d = c('02.24*', '78.78')

unlist(codes)[match(d,unlist(codes,use.names = F))]
 traincodes2 traincodes13 
    "02.24*"      "78.78"
```

Comment: Thanks! But, can we avoid adding a position to names in result? in our case just: traincodes2 traincodes1 (not traincodes13)?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
    # Your codes.
    codes <- list(
      traincodes = list(c('2.29*', '99.49'), c('78.78')),   
      traincodes2 = list(c('02.24*')))

    # Target.
    d = c('02.24*', '78.78')

    # Check where in your code a element of d is found, then extract that element from code and return it. 
enter code here
    #If you want just the position remove the code[[ ]]
    lapply(codes, function(code) {
      code[[which(d %in% code)]]
    })
```

which returns:

```
$traincodes
[1] "78.78"

$traincodes2
[1] "02.24*"
```